# iris fuel 50 not able to download from playstore it is showing insufficient storage but i have big storage space in SD card

Tags: applications, google-play-store, internal-storage

iris fuel 50 not able to download from playstore it is showing insufficient storage but i have big storage space in SD card(2GB in internal memory and 29GB in sdcard but unable to download )

Comment: Welcomed to android enthusiasts! Please check our [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) tag wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I think there're some solutions for you:

**Uninstall the Google Play Store updates:**

1. Open your Settings > Apps
2. Find and select Google Play Store from the list
3. On stock Android 6+, press the menu icon in the top right corner of your screen menu
4. Press Uninstall Updates

**Move large apps to your SD card**

**Get your apk file from PC and then transfer them to your device** : There're variety of third party store like [Download Apk file for PC for free](http://choilieng.com) .This site is safe and free of malware so don't worry. 
Hope these solutions can help!